# Magento 2.4.3-p1 flush cache error consumer

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento-cron, magento2.4.2-p1, magento-cache-management

i use magento 2.4.3-p1 and everything is works fine except when i flush cache i got the following:

EDIT: var/log, system.log, debug.log, cron.log everything fine!

Screenshot of cron task list:
[image]

```
Warning: include(/home/customer/www/domain.hr/public_html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/Api/GuestTotalsInformationManagementInterface.php): failed to open stream: Too many open files in /home/customer/www/domain.hr/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: file_put_contents(/home/customer/www/domain.hr/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---80c_MAGE): failed to open stream: Too many open files in /home/customer/www/domain.hr/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 691
```

INFO:
-Magento is upgraded from ver. 2.4.2 to 2.4.3-p1.
-If you need more information about the server, tell me and I will write to you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper permission and have to give the proper user to /var/cache folder.

Apache user means www-data don't have proper permission at that folder.

Comment: Can you help me a litle more. how to set permission? im trying but i got the same

Answer (score 0):

Can you help me a litle more. how to set permission? im trying but i got the same

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this article to set the correct permissions for your project
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Or another fix you can see is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14749074